# Making control.Parsecontrol(HTMLString) filter Literalcontrol by Div elements instead of Br elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

This is the first question I ask on this site, so I apologise for any muckups I make in advance, I will however try to ask this question as best as possible.

I'm finding my problem a little difficult to explain, but it boils down to this:

I have a large string of HTML that is generated by retrieving an XML file from a Web Service and using XSLT to transform it into a large string of HTML. I then parse it into a Control collection, add some event handlers and add it to a HTMLPlaceholder and hooray everything works just fine.

However, since this HTML String contains pretty much my entire website and is being run on hand terminals that cannot handle all the markup at once, I filter the markup I send, but this presents a problem.

`Div` elements cannot be filtered out without losing the `Div` element I want to keep. This is because Parsecontrol chops my `Div` elements in half and turns them into Literalcontrols, which are sorted by `br` elements.

Showing my code is a little hard, but here is an example of what happens:

```
//html contains the auto generated HTML 
ctrl = ParseControl (html);

            for ( int i = ctrl.Controls.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
            {

                string MenuId = "";
                Control theControl = ctrl.Controls[i];

                if ( theControl is Button )
                // Code that filters buttons
                if ( theControl is TextBox)
                // Code that filters textboxes

                if ( theControl is LiteralControl )
                {
                    LiteralControl literal = theControl as LiteralControl;

                   //This checks if the Div element I'm looking for exists
                   //If it does, I want to keep it
                    bool contains = literal.Text.Contains ("<div id=\"" + ParentDiv);
                    if ( contains )
                        MenuId = ParentDiv;
                }

                if ( MenuId != ParentDiv )
                {
                    ctrl.Controls.RemoveAt (i);
                }

            }
```

It's when I get to the LiteralControl part that things go wrong. Buttons and Textfields work fine. The LiteralControl however, chops my Div elements in half and are filtered by `br` elements. My `div` elements look like the following(Edited for brevity):

```
<div class="hide" id="TB_24000" >
<br>
<Textbox elements>
<Button elements>
<Label elements>
<br>
<Textbox elements>
<Button elements>
<Label elements>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnBack" value="Tilbage" class="BackandResetButtons" onclick="backButton(this,document.getElementById('MenuLevel1'),document.getElementById('TB_24000')); return false;"></div>
```

But my LiteralControl elements look like the following(unedited):

```
<br><input type="button" id="btnBack" value="Tilbage" class="BackandResetButtons" onclick="backButton(this, document.getElementById('TB_33999'),document.getElementById('TB_38400'));&#xA;          "></div>
```

And the next:

```
<br><label class="label">FRAGT</label><br>
```

And the next:

```
<br><label class="label">SPEDITØR</label><br>
```

As you can see, my LiteralControls are based upon `br` elements, but the problem is that I want to filter based on `Div` elements. However, it doesn't seem to be possible without resorting to dirty and frankly unwanted hacks.

So my question is: How do I filter based on `Div` elements instead of `Br` elements? I can filter buttons and textboxes that add functionality just fine, but my layout and site is dependent on my `Div` elements being there.

Comment: Are you saying that when you call `ctrl.Controls.RemoveAt(i);` it is removing the start of the `<div>` but leaves the contents and the end of the `</div>`?

Comment: The div elements that I want are sometimes in the LiteralControl element, the problem is however that it has child br elements, and that's where the Literalcontrol always begins and ends, which effectively means that I only get a chopped version of my Div elements, and all the child label elements are seperated because they have a br element infront of them(see above)

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your `BR` elements like this:  `<br />`  I think that the parser is getting confused by the `BR` element with no closing tag.

Comment: I tried deleting the <br /> elements and now it filters on input instead. This issue doesn't seem to be specifically related to <br /> elements, but rather the fact that ParseControl turns the HTML into LiteralControls quite arbitrarily